# Best practice: local variables in a function (explicit vs implicit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

Is there a recommended style when it comes to the use local variables inside a function? Should we use more explicit local variables as in style 1 or not as in style 2?

Two possible styles:

Style 1:

```
import re


def doc_to_lower(url_raw):
    url_lower = [word.lower() for word in url_raw]
    return url_lower


def process_data(url_raw):
    url_split = re.split('//|/|-', url_raw)
    url_lower = doc_to_lower(url_split)
    return url_lower

url = 'http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/41653935'
tokens = process_data(url)

for token in tokens:
    print(token)
```

Style 2:

```
import re


def doc_to_lower(url_raw):
    return [word.lower() for word in url_raw]


def process_data(url_raw):
    return doc_to_lower(re.split('//|/|-', url_raw))

url = 'http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/41653935'
tokens = process_data(url)

for token in tokens:
    print(token)
```

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." - Just look at the answers: "I prefer this, I think, my personal..."

Comment: No. (twelve more)

Comment: Opinions aside, the step-by-step version of style 1 has a clear advantage when it comes to exceptions. Python isn't very good in explaining where exactly in an expression an exception has happened, so if you get one during assigning `url_split` that will help narrow the reason down very quickly, while getting one in the complex `return` statement of style 2 will leave you more or less guessing. Imagine `a+b+c+d+e+f` resulting in `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. Which one was the culprit? But it's a trade-off. Splitting too much will render the code unreadable.

Comment: @Alfe Assuming your code is well tested, I don't see how your exaplanation apply for the question.

Comment: @scharette That's a bit like saying we won't need stack traces because well-tested code doesn't produce them.  Code may be well-tested and still some call may result in an exception you've never encountered before (e. g. a network timeout, an edge case you haven't thought of etc.).  Good code is written in a way so that unexpected behavior leads to situations which still help finding the rare bug.  Writing everything in a functional style (as elegant as it may be) doesn't help there.

Comment: @Alfe I see your point and I could not agree more. But for the cases stated in the question I disagree with you. Anyway, as I said in my answer, it is about opinion at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefef style 2, because I find it easier to read.

I can think of two reasons to use style 1 in certain cases:

1. When the expression becomes very complex. Using style 1 you can split up parts of the expression and assign it a readable name.
2. When the value of a subexpression must be available for an assert statement, debugging or a test case.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure this is a case where personal opinions will arise. But for me, situation 2 represent a more pythonic way of representing things.

The main reason of my answer is the fact that your function name in this case says it all. I declare local variable only if I have to or if it helps for readability.

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

To demonstrate my answer take this part of your code,

Style 1:

```
def process_data(url_raw):
    url_split = re.split('//|/|-', url_raw)
    url_lower = doc_to_lower(url_split)
    return url_lower
```

Style 2:

```
def process_data(url_raw):
    return doc_to_lower(re.split('//|/|-', url_raw))
```

If I were to reuse your code, at a glance I'd think style 1 return a lowered url and would understand that in style 2 the function is used to processed data.

I'm not trying to say that I'm an expert or anything and this is debatable, I'm just trying to clarify my point.

Answer (score 1):

Great question and well done for thinking about readability all the time, making it easier down the line.

I think my answer would have to be follow the coding standard of your place of work where possible. This is most important, there should be consistency with the other developers you are working with.

If there is no coding standard, arrange a meeting and write one up together. That way you're all workingfrom the same script (pardon the pun) and the code will be readable to everyone.

My personal preference would be the explicit version. For me it would be clearer what was going on and thus reduce my own errors. However I understand that some would see this as a slight overkill in simple examples. I guess it comes down to what languages you learnt first and how and where you learnt them.